# Fix HTML email template in yandex mail

Tags: html, css, html-email, newsletter, email-templates

I'm sending template to my yandex mail, everything okay.[image]

But i need to forward this template from yandex mail. When i click forward, template going to left.[image]

And also somehow deleting some css or i don't know what is going on here. But it shows like this. It shows like in mobile version. [image]

I added Margin: 0 auto; in first div, and template now in center. But blocks shows like mobile version. Can someone help me please?
Here is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
    <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
    <title>Email Template 1</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap');

        table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        td {
            padding: 0;
        }

        p {
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        img {
            border: 0;
            border-width: 0;
        }

        a {
            color: #277fd2;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 599.98px) {
            .px-600-0 {
                padding-left: 0 !important;
                padding-right: 0 !important;
            }

            .pt-600-0 {
                padding-top: 0 !important;
            }

            img.third-img-last {
                width: 200px !important;
                max-width: 200px !important;
            }

            .d-600-none {
                display: none !important;
            }

            .pr-large {
                padding-right: 140px !important;
            }

            .center-text-mobile {
                text-align: center !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 549.98px) {
            .pt-550-0 {
                padding-top: 0 !important;
            }

            .pr-large {
                padding-right: 100px !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 499.98px) {
            .pt-500-0 {
                padding-top: 0 !important;
            }

            .pr-large {
                padding-right: 60px !important;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 399.98px) {
            .banner {
                height: auto !important;
                padding-top: 50px !important;
                padding-bottom: 30px !important;
            }

            .px-sm-0 {
                padding-left: 0 !important;
                padding-right: 0 !important;
            }

            .pt-400-0 {
                padding-top: 0 !important;
            }

            img.third-img {
                width: 200px !important;
                max-width: 200px !important;
            }

            .pr-large {
                padding-right: 25px !important;
            }
        }


        :root {
            color-scheme: light dark;
            supported-color-schemes: light dark;
        }

        @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

            body,
            center,
            table,
            .darkmode-bg {
                background: #2d2d2d !important;
                color: #ffffff !important;
            }

            .darkmode-transparent {
                background-color: transparent !important;
            }
        }
    </style>



</head>

<body
    style="Margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#F6F9FC;">


    <center style="width: 100%;table-layout:fixed;background-color: #F6F9FC;padding-bottom: 40px;">
        <div style="max-width: 600px;background-color: #ffffff;box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);">





            <table align="center"
                style="border-spacing:0;color:#3D3D3D;font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif, Arial, Helvetica;background-color: #ffffff;Margin:0;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;width: 100%;max-width: 600px;"
                role="presentation">


                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">

                            <tr>
                                <td
                                    style="background-color:#277fd2;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:8px;width:100%;width:600px;text-align:center;">
                                    <a href="https://www.example.com"><img
                                            src="https://i.ibb.co/M6WP8Xy/w3newbie-white.png" alt="logo" width="180"
                                            style="border-width:0;" border="0"></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="banner" background="https://i.ibb.co/fS3mbtd/600x350-2.jpg" width="600" height="350"
                        style="background-position: center top;">



                        <table class="darkmode-transparent" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="600" align="center" valign="middle">
                                    <table class="darkmode-transparent" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
                                        role="presentation">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <table class="darkmode-transparent" role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>



                                                        <td valign="middle" align="center"
                                                            style="padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom:15px;vertical-align:middle;">
                                                            <p style="font-size: 30px;color: #515151;font-weight:bold;">
                                                                COMPANY NEWSLETTER</p>
                                                            <p align="center" style="font-size:18px;color: #515151;">The
                                                                latest from our business.</p>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <table class="darkmode-transparent" align="center" border="0"
                                                    cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <td align="center" style="border-radius:4px;" bgcolor="#2cbc8c">
                                                            <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank"
                                                                style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;color: #ffffff;background-color: #2cbc8c;border:1px solid #2cbc8c;border-radius:4px;padding:12px 18px;display: inline-block;">GET
                                                                STARTED
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25"> </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>



                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                                <td
                                    style="padding-top:22px;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:50px;padding-left:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">
                                    <p style=" font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom: 5px;">Email Template
                                        <strong style="color: #277fd2;">Development</strong>
                                    </p>
                                    <p style="font-size:15px; line-height: 23px; padding-bottom: 18px;">Responsive HTML
                                        Email Templates that you can build around. Responsive HTML Email Templates that
                                        you can build around. Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around.
                                        Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around.</p>

                                    <table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                        role="presentation">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center">
                                                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>

                                                        <td align="center" style="border-radius:4px;" bgcolor="#277fd2">
                                                            <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank"
                                                                style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;color: #ffffff;background-color: #277fd2;border:1px solid #277fd2;border-radius:4px;padding:10px 18px;display: inline-block;">Get
                                                                Started
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td align="center" width="18"></td>

                                                        <td align="center" style="border-radius:4px;" bgcolor="#2cbc8c">
                                                            <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank"
                                                                style="font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;color: #ffffff;background-color: #2cbc8c;border:1px solid #2cbc8c;border-radius:4px;padding:10px 18px;display: inline-block;">View
                                                                Demo
                                                            </a>
                                                        </td>

                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing: 0;" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="5" style="background-color: #277fd2;"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/JFX5QvX/shadow-2.jpg" width="600" alt=""
                            style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:600px;">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;" role="presentation">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="three-columns"
                                    style="padding-top:40px;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:30px;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;">



                                    <table class="column"
                                        style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"
                                        role="presentation">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="padding px-sm-0"
                                                style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <table class="content" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center;"
                                                    role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a href="https://www.example.com"><img class="third-img"
                                                                    src="https://i.ibb.co/M56gsgd/380x280.png"
                                                                    width="150" alt=""
                                                                    style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:150px;height:auto;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <table align="center" width="100%" border="0"
                                                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"
                                                                style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center;">
                                                                <tr>


                                                                    <td style="padding-top:15px;">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="font-size:17px;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;">
                                                                            APPLE WATCH</p>
                                                                        <p style="font-size:15px;">Responsive HTML Email
                                                                            Templates that you can build around to
                                                                            master email development.</p>
                                                                        <a href="https://www.example.com"
                                                                            target="_blank"
                                                                            style="font-size: 15px;line-height:20px;font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;color: #277fd2; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Learn
                                                                            more..</a>
                                                                    </td>



                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>



                                    <table class="column"
                                        style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"
                                        role="presentation">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="padding px-sm-0"
                                                style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <table class="content" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center;"
                                                    role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a href="https://www.example.com"><img class="third-img"
                                                                    src="https://i.ibb.co/p15Gw9H/380x280-2.png"
                                                                    width="150" alt=""
                                                                    style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:150px;height:auto;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <table align="center" width="100%" border="0"
                                                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"
                                                                style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center;">
                                                                <tr>



                                                                    <td style="padding-top:15px;">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="font-size:17px;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;">
                                                                            EAR PODS</p>
                                                                        <p style="font-size:15px;">Responsive HTML Email
                                                                            Templates that you can build around to
                                                                            master email development.</p>
                                                                        <a href="https://www.example.com"
                                                                            target="_blank"
                                                                            style="font-size: 15px;line-height:20px;font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;color: #277fd2; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Learn
                                                                            more..</a>
                                                                    </td>


                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>



                                    <table class="column"
                                        style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;"
                                        role="presentation">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="padding px-sm-0"
                                                style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <table class="content" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center;"
                                                    role="presentation">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <a href="https://www.example.com"><img
                                                                    class="third-img-last"
                                                                    src="https://i.ibb.co/Hpn49Y1/380x280-3.png"
                                                                    width="150" alt=""
                                                                    style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:150px;height:auto;"></a>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td align="center">
                                                            <table align="center" width="100%" border="0"
                                                                cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"
                                                                style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center;">
                                                                <tr>



                                                                    <td style="padding-top:15px;">
                                                                        <p
                                                                            style="font-size:17px;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;">
                                                                            WATCH BANDS</p>
                                                                        <p style="font-size:15px;">Responsive HTML Email
                                                                            Templates that you can build around to
                                                                            master email development.</p>
                                                                        <a href="https://www.example.com"
                                                                            target="_blank"
                                                                            style="font-size: 15px;line-height:20px;color: #277fd2; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Learn
                                                                            more..</a>
                                                                    </td>


                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>



                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>


            </table>


        </div>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very common for emails clients to filter HTML and CSS features when viewing an email. And it's even more common for them to do so when forwarding an email. It's usually not recommended to ever test the render of an email using forward as you won’t forward your original HTML code but instead the code as transformed by the email client.

Here are a few links about this:

- [Why Forwarding Emails is so Bad](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/why_forwarding_emails_is_so_bad/), by Email on Acid
- [What Causes HTML Email Breaks When Forwarding?](https://www.litmus.com/blog/when-forwarded-emails-break), by Litmus
- [Super Mail Forward: an email that evolves as you forward it](https://www.hteumeuleu.com/2016/super-mail-forward-an-email-that-evolves-as-you-forward-it/), by myself :)

Answer (score -1):

Emails do not handle advanced CSS or HTML well, so the ideal is to use tables, including for positioning and spacing.

I replaced  and created a table, centered the td inside it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark"><meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark"><title>Email Template 1</title><style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap);table{border-spacing:0}td{padding:0}p{font-size:15px}img{border:0;border-width:0}a{color:#277fd2;text-decoration:none}@media screen and (max-width:599.98px){.px-600-0{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important}.pt-600-0{padding-top:0!important}img.third-img-last{width:200px!important;max-width:200px!important}.d-600-none{display:none!important}.pr-large{padding-right:140px!important}.center-text-mobile{text-align:center!important}}@media screen and (max-width:549.98px){.pt-550-0{padding-top:0!important}.pr-large{padding-right:100px!important}}@media screen and (max-width:499.98px){.pt-500-0{padding-top:0!important}.pr-large{padding-right:60px!important}}@media screen and (max-width:399.98px){.banner{height:auto!important;padding-top:50px!important;padding-bottom:30px!important}.px-sm-0{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important}.pt-400-0{padding-top:0!important}img.third-img{width:200px!important;max-width:200px!important}.pr-large{padding-right:25px!important}}:root{color-scheme:light dark;supported-color-schemes:light dark}@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark){.darkmode-bg,body,center,table{background:#2d2d2d!important;color:#fff!important}.darkmode-transparent{background-color:transparent!important}}</style></head><body style="Margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;min-width:100%;background-color:#f6f9fc"><table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;background-color:#f6f9fc;padding-bottom:40px"><tr><td align="center"><div style="max-width:600px;background-color:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2)"><table align="center" style="border-spacing:0;color:#3d3d3d;font-family:Lato,sans-serif,Arial,Helvetica;background-color:#fff;Margin:0;padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;width:100%;max-width:600px" role="presentation"><tr><td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0"><table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" role="presentation"><tr><td style="background-color:#277fd2;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:8px;width:100%;width:600px;text-align:center"><a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/M6WP8Xy/w3newbie-white.png" alt="logo" width="180" style="border-width:0" border="0"></a></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td class="banner" background="https://i.ibb.co/fS3mbtd/600x350-2.jpg" width="600" height="350" style="background-position:center top"><table class="darkmode-transparent" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td width="600" align="center" valign="middle"><table class="darkmode-transparent" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation"><tr><td align="center"><table class="darkmode-transparent" role="presentation"><tr><td valign="middle" align="center" style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:15px;vertical-align:middle"><p style="font-size:30px;color:#515151;font-weight:700">COMPANY NEWSLETTER</p><p align="center" style="font-size:18px;color:#515151">The latest from our business.</p></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><table class="darkmode-transparent" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td align="center" style="border-radius:4px" bgcolor="#2cbc8c"><a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#2cbc8c;border:1px solid #2cbc8c;border-radius:4px;padding:12px 18px;display:inline-block">GET STARTED</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td height="25"></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0"><table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" role="presentation"><tr><td style="padding-top:22px;padding-right:20px;padding-bottom:50px;padding-left:20px;width:100%;text-align:center;font-size:20px"><p style="font-size:20px;font-weight:700;padding-bottom:5px">Email Template<strong style="color:#277fd2">Development</strong></p><p style="font-size:15px;line-height:23px;padding-bottom:18px">Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around. Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around. Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around. Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around.</p><table align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td align="center"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation"><tr><td align="center" style="border-radius:4px" bgcolor="#277fd2"><a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#277fd2;border:1px solid #277fd2;border-radius:4px;padding:10px 18px;display:inline-block">Get Started</a></td><td align="center" width="18"></td><td align="center" style="border-radius:4px" bgcolor="#2cbc8c"><a href="https://example.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:16px;font-weight:700;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;background-color:#2cbc8c;border:1px solid #2cbc8c;border-radius:4px;padding:10px 18px;display:inline-block">View Demo</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0"><table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" role="presentation"><tr><td height="5" style="background-color:#277fd2"></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/JFX5QvX/shadow-2.jpg" width="600" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:600px"></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-top:0;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0"><table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0" role="presentation"><tr><td class="three-columns" style="padding-top:40px;padding-right:0;padding-bottom:30px;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0"><table class="column" style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" role="presentation"><tr><td class="padding px-sm-0" style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:10px"><table class="content" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center" role="presentation"><tr><td><a href="https://www.example.com"><img class="third-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/M56gsgd/380x280.png" width="150" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:150px;height:auto"></a></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center"><tr><td style="padding-top:15px"><p style="font-size:17px;line-height:20px;font-weight:700">APPLE WATCH</p><p style="font-size:15px">Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around to master email development.</p><a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px;line-height:20px;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;color:#277fd2;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block">Learn more..</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table class="column" style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" role="presentation"><tr><td class="padding px-sm-0" style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:10px"><table class="content" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center" role="presentation"><tr><td><a href="https://www.example.com"><img class="third-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/p15Gw9H/380x280-2.png" width="150" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:150px;height:auto"></a></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center"><tr><td style="padding-top:15px"><p style="font-size:17px;line-height:20px;font-weight:700">EAR PODS</p><p style="font-size:15px">Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around to master email development.</p><a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px;line-height:20px;font-family:Lato,sans-serif;color:#277fd2;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block">Learn more..</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table><table class="column" style="border-spacing:0;width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top" role="presentation"><tr><td class="padding px-sm-0" style="padding-top:20px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:20px;padding-left:10px"><table class="content" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center" role="presentation"><tr><td><a href="https://www.example.com"><img class="third-img-last" src="https://i.ibb.co/Hpn49Y1/380x280-3.png" width="150" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:150px;height:auto"></a></td></tr><tr><td align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="border-spacing:0;text-align:center"><tr><td style="padding-top:15px"><p style="font-size:17px;line-height:20px;font-weight:700">WATCH BANDS</p><p style="font-size:15px">Responsive HTML Email Templates that you can build around to master email development.</p><a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" style="font-size:15px;line-height:20px;color:#277fd2;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block">Learn more..</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div></td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Comment: when i send it to yandex mail everything is good. But when i try to forward it shows again like this. (like in 3th photo)